# How is this not formatted correctly?

Tags: support, code-formatting, editing-help

I'm trying to post this as a question... but I when I try to submit it I get an error saying that code snippets are not blocked off.... help please!

---

I'm having trouble debugging this. Here's my scenario:

I'm using android studio. I'm switching to use the appcompat-v7 library. Unfortunately I only have access to Samsung devices running 4.2.2 (bad luck) which are affected by [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657348/appcompat-v7-v21-0-0-causing-crash-on-samsung-devices-with-android-v4-2-2). I'm using the temporary solution provided with proguard, applying the following lines in my proguard file.

```
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.** {*;}
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.*
-dontwarn retrofit.client.OkClient
-dontwarn rx.internal.util.unsafe.*
```

The above lines are used because I'm getting error of this sort, and this was the workaround provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974231/proguard-hell-cant-find-referenced-class)

```
Warning: retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning: retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
```

If I run a simple "Hello World" application where I'm not using retrofit to fetch data, I'm able to get the ActionBarActivity on a screen of my Samsung 4.2.2 device using this proguard workaround. However, when I run my application that uses retrofit I get the following stack trace.

I'm using retrofit-1.8.0.jar and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3

Any insight into this would be much appreciated. Until then, I'll just avoid using the appcompat libraries for testing purposes.

```
2-18 13:14:24.494    8430-8430/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey/com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
        at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter.create(Unknown Source)
                                getMethodInfo
                                logAndReplaceRequest
                                logException
                                access$000
                                access$002
                                access$400
                                access$500
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at $Proxy0.b(Native Method)
        at com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey.model.RetrofitManager.fetchBuilding(Unknown Source)
                                                                fetchBuildings
                                                                access$000
        at com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey.SplashScreenActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5355)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Also I don't know where this issue should be posted... please redirect if this is incorrect

Comment: I assume the question is, why isn't the content after the second line allowed to be posted by the system?

Comment: You should probably not use backticks for large blocks of code; just indent over four spaces.

Comment: Yes please. That exception looks horrible using code snippet highlights.

Comment: An exception is usually block-quoted anyways, its not code

Comment: @Bradley, a code block with syntax highlighting disabled may be a better choice, depending on the backtrace format.

Comment: meta suggestion: where 'edit' button is grayed out (as it is on this question for me) a 'show formatting' button should appear alongside it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. I swear I tried making it look pretty the first time and something was bugging out making it not submittable nor easy to read. It's all tidied up and posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558433/appcompat-v7-with-samsung-4-2-2-device-proguard-enabled-crashing-app-using-retr

Also, did I block-quote that correctly? It looks nice but is what I did follow Stackoverflow semantics?

Comment: I removed the `bug` tag because this is not a bug. It's a mistake in the way you formatted the code, but the markup and site here are working correctly.